# Does OUTPUT_PATH key and sys.stdout do same function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across a the following code to find difference between diagonal sums of a square matrix.

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
def diagonalDifference(arr):
    d1=0
    d2=0
    a=n-1
    print(arr[1][1])
    for i in range(0,n):
        d1+=arr[i][i]
        d2+=arr[i][a]
        a-=1
    if d1>d2:
        return d1-d2
    else:
        return d2-d1
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    n = int(input().strip())
    arr = []
    for _ in range(n):
        arr.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))
    result = diagonalDifference(arr)
    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')
    fptr.close()
```

When I replace the line `fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')` with `fptr = sys.stdout`, the output doesnot differ.
So, what's the difference between functions of these two statements?

Comment: I don't have that env var on Ubuntu 18.04. What OS are you using? What is the variable's value?

Comment: BTW it would help to provide a [mre], which I think would be just `import os; print('hello world!', file=os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'])`

Comment: @wjandrea in Ubuntu it shows key error because I also don't have env var. But in windows system or on online compilers it works. In linux, it perform same job when that line is replaced by ```fptr = sys.stdout```. I can't understand how this works?

Comment: Well what is it - i.e. what's the value of `os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH']`?

Comment: I also don't have that env var on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: @wjandrea this enviroment variable can be created manually too.